# Set different heading according to rules

Tags: range, netlogo, agent, heading

What I want to do is to create agents that move randomly in NetLogo world so that it will be quite similar as in real world (since these agents are based on animals, so there shouldn't be any specific codes saying they need to do this or that, most living things move randomly.)

Here is what I plan, I will give a percentage on which direction they will choose, but mostly they will walk straight, here is how I plan it:

1. if percentage <= 85, heading should be in range 315 - 45
2. if percentage <= 90, heading should be in range 45 - 315
3. if percentage <= 95, heading should be in range 315 - 225
4. if percentage <= 100, heading should be in range 225 - 315

Here is image of what I plan to do, `p = percentage`, 
(I am bad at explaining in words)

[image: I am bad at explaining in words]

here is my code

```
 to random-behave

  let p random-float 100

  if-else p <= 85
  [ set  heading heading + 45
    set heading heading - 45]
  [ if-else p <= 90
    [ set heading heading + 45
      set  heading heading + 135]
    [ if-else p <= 95
      [ set  heading heading + 135
        set heading heading + 225]
      [set  heading heading + 225
       set heading heading + 315]
    ]
  ]

  if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]
  fd 1
end
```

I have some serious error while coding for heading since I don't know how to implement the range that I need.

And is **there overlapping heading range happen** if I used the one I mention above? Since `315 - 45, 45 - 135`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you find an elegant solution for this? I'm still looking at this...

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to explain in words what your code is doing- there are definitely some problems with your approach to headings here. For a breakdown of what the `ifelse` statements are being evaluated, have a look at the comments I've inserted into your version. You'll notice that you're adding or subtracting to a turtle heading multiple times in a single code chunk:

```
to random-behave-old
  let p random-float 100

  if-else p <= 85 [
    ; if p is less than or equal to 85, 
    ; add 45 to heading, then subtract 45 from heading 
    set heading heading + 45
    set heading heading - 45
  ] [ 
    if-else p <= 90 [ 
      ; if p is greater than 85, but less than
      ; or equal to 90, add 45 to heading, then
      ; add another 135 to heading
      set heading heading + 45
      set  heading heading + 135
    ] [ 
      if-else p <= 95 [ 
        ; if p is greater than 90, but less than 
        ; or equal to 95, add 135 to heading, 
        ; then add 225 to heading
        set heading heading + 135
        set heading heading + 225
      ] [
        ; if p is greater than 95, add 225 to heading
        ; then add 315 to the heading.
        set  heading heading + 225
        set heading heading + 315
      ]
    ]
  ]
  if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]
  fd 1
end
```

Now, if I understand you correctly, you want your turtles to mostly move forward the direction they are facing, is that true? Or do you want them to mostly move towards heading 0 (more or less north in the NetLogo world). Assuming the former, have a look at this version of your code. Here, rather than adding to a heading, the turtles just use `right-turn` (`rt`) to change their heading.

```
to random-behave
  let p random-float 100

  if-else p <= 85 [
    ; if p is less than or equal to 85, 
    ; right-turn a random value from -45 to 45
    rt random 91 - 45
  ] [ 
    if-else p <= 90 [ 
      ; if p is greater than 85, but less than
      ; or equal to 90, right-turn 90, then 
      ; right-turn a further -45 to 45
      rt 90 + random 91 - 45
      print "Turning right!"
    ] [ 
      if-else p <= 95 [ 
        ; if p is greater than 90, but less than 
        ; or equal to 95, right-turn 180, then 
        ; right-turn a further -45 to 45
        rt 180 + random 91 - 45
        print "Turning around!"
      ] [
        ; if p is greater than 95, right-turn 270, then 
        ; right-turn a further -45 to 45
        rt 270 + random 91 - 45
        print "Turning left!"
      ]
    ]
  ]
  if not can-move? 1 [ rt 180 ]
  fd 1
end
```

If in fact you want them to move mostly a specific direction, you can modify the above. For example, to move mostly north, use something like `set heading 0 + random 91 - 45`; to move mostly east, something like `set heading 90 + random 91 - 45`.

Comment: I plan to code turtles to move randomly in world, p is for percentage of what they will choose for their heading, most of it is north since we usually move ahead, That is why the percentage or p is equal to 85% while others is 5%

Comment: @linda - Yes, I understand that. I was just trying to clarify that your description of movement should not be "if p <= 85, heading should be in range 315 - 45" because that would make the turtle face up/north in the NetLogo world, rather than to continue forward with respect to its current heading.

Comment: Ohh, now I get it, meaning that if I implement that p <= 85, range should be 315-45, it will make the turtles unable to follow their heading now, which is weird. They should be able to follow their own heading instead of p <=85. Thanks for the head up, I'll try to use your code and see what happen, thanks for your time  :D

Comment: @linda - Yes, that's what I meant- if p <= 85, they should move in roughly the same direction they were already facing. Cheers!

Comment: if I want to show the value of p for each turtle, how can I do that? I tried to put as `turtles-own [p]`, but I can't declare `let p random-float 100` since it's already been declared in `turtles-own`, but then p's value doesn't change. I tried to `print p`, but then, I'm not sure which turtles it indicates to.

Comment: @linda - You'd have to use `set p random-float 100`- `let` is to create temporary variables, whereas `set` can modify declared or already-created temporary variables